# How to fix error: "CORS policy " when making a post request in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to make a POST request to the Microsoft cognitive translate service, but get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/post' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
core.js:15723 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/post", ok: false, …}
```

I made a similar api POST request in node.js from the docs provided by Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/quickstart-nodejs-translate

This worked totally fine, but when I tried in Angular I kept facing the same error since this morning.

My end product will be a option to translate 90% of the page. Now I only want to translate a word to work it out further.

If there is anything simpler to translate some specific text on the website I'm more than happy to switch to something else.

My code so far:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslatedText } from './TranslatedText';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class TranslateService {

  readonly request = Request;
  readonly uuidv4 = uuid();

  readonly subscriptionKey: string = 'MYTRANSLATIONKEY';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  options = {
    method: 'POST',
    baseUrl: 'https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/',
    url: 'translate',
    qs: {
      'api-version': '3.0',
      'to': 'de',
    },
    headers: {
      'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': this.subscriptionKey,
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'X-ClientTraceId': this.uuidv4.toString()
    },
    body: [{
      'text': 'Hello World!'
    }],
    json: true,
  };


  readKey() {

    if (!this.subscriptionKey) {
      throw new Error('Environment variable for your subscription key is not set.')
    };
  }

  getTranslation() {
    console.log("api call gelukt");
    return this.http.post('https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/post', this.options.body, this.options);
  }



}
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '../translate.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-translate',
  templateUrl: './translate.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./translate.component.css']
})

export class TranslateComponent implements OnInit {



  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  getTranslation() {

    return this.translateService.getTranslation().subscribe( (data ) => console.log(data))

  }




}
```

My expecting result was to get a json Something like this in the console:

```
[
    {
        "detectedLanguage": {
            "language": "en",
            "score": 1.0
        },
        "translations": [
            {
                "text": "Hallo Welt!",
                "to": "de"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

But I'm getting the error showed earlier

Comment: hey, you should read more about CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). bluntly speaking, your backend doesn't allow requests from your domain (localhost).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for development purpose you can disable the browser security then use can use cross orgin.

- **In Chrome:**

chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security

go to this path and run in command prompt to open browser. then you can able to call call cross orgin http requests.

Answer (score 1):

Please check with the backend team to handle CORS origin. They need to enable CORS to avoid this error. It's not recommended to handle it in the browser or http level.

Comment: We decided to make a web API  that accepts CORS and get data from there.